# How to export Mathematica data in columns

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm very new to Mathematica. I want to use it as a data source for gnuplot (I know Mathematica can plot too), it uses a file format with data in columns and a space between each column on each row. Like this:

```
x y
1 123
2 234
4 456
```

etc.

I've come as far as to create this expression:

```
{CountryData["G8"], CountryData[#, "GDP"] & /@ CountryData["G8"]} // Transpose // Grid
```

This creates a table just like I want it. Now, how can I export this to a file not as matrix but as a table like it appears in Mathematica?

Comment: You may find this link of use: http://forums.wolfram.com/student-support/topics/24465

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `CountryData` usage can be streamlined a bit using the map operator `/@`:

```
{#, CountryData[#, "GDP"]} & /@ CountryData["G8"],
```

Combining this with `Export` you get this:

```
Export[
  "C:\\Users\\Sjoerd\\Desktop\\tabel.txt", 
  {#, CountryData[#, "GDP"]} & /@ CountryData["G8"], 
  "Table", 
 "FieldSeparators" -> " "
]
```

Replace the above file path with something appropriate for your situation.

Answer (score 4):

Mathematica supports a wide range of [Export formats](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24ExportFormats.html). Something like `Export["mytable.csv",nameofexpression]` should do the trick, `Export["file.dat",nameofexpression,"Table"]` for space /tab delimited.

[This tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ImportingAndExportingData.html) should help.